# Perform Sum product after filtering the data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to perform sum product of filtered data.

Below example is general example without filters

`=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(Met!Y2:Y3299,Metrics!AE2:AE3299)/Sum(Met!AE2:AE3299),"")`

Now my use case here is in the sheet "Met", I will need to filter the data first and then perform sum product only to those filtered rows and I am getting incorrect output

`=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Met!Y2:Y3299, phmet[g_name], G2, phmet[channel], "Ph"),SUMIFS(Met!AE2:AE3299, phmet[g_name], G2, phmet[channel], "Ph"))/SUMIFS(Met!AE2:AE3299, phmet[g_name], G2, phmet[channel], "Ph"),"")`

In the about, I am inputting the formula in another sheet where it filters a data table in sheet 'Met' (first filters Y column with the value in G column, then filters AE column with the string "Ph" and to the output, I need to do sum product just like shown in the example on third line of the body). phmet is the table name in the sheet 'Met'